# Increment property int (self.int++)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, integer

How can you increment a integer property?

You can't do `self.integer++`, you can do `integer++`, but I'm not sure wether or not that will retain it..

Will the last one retain the value of "integer"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`integer++` works because you are accessing the `integer` directly and assigning a new value to `integer` instead of sending a message and using accessors. Assuming that `integer` is declared as an `NSInteger` property the following statements are will have the same effect on the value of integer, however direct access is not KVO compliant.

```
[self setInteger:0];
self.integer = self.integer + 1; // use generated accessors
NSLog(@"Integer is :%d",[self integer]); // Integer is: 1
integer++;
NSLog(@"Integer is :%d",[self integer]); // Integer is: 2
```

Comment: Ok, thanks :) [blahblahblah, trying to fill this comment up, stupid char-limit.]

Answer (score 0):

I believe Obj-C was updated in the last year or two so that this kind of code works. I wrote a quick test and found the following code is all valid and works:

in my .h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface TheAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSUInteger value;
}

@property NSUInteger otherValue;

- (NSUInteger) value;
- (void) setValue:(NSUInteger)value;

@end
```

In my .m:

```
#import "TheAppDelegate.h"

@implementation TheAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    value = self.otherValue = 1;
    NSLog(@"%lu %lu", (unsigned long)value, (unsigned long)self.value);
    NSLog(@"%lu %lu", (unsigned long)_otherValue, (unsigned long)self.otherValue);
    self.value++;
    self.otherValue++;
    NSLog(@"%lu %lu", (unsigned long)value, (unsigned long)self.value);
    NSLog(@"%lu %lu", (unsigned long)_otherValue, (unsigned long)self.otherValue);
}

- (NSUInteger) value
{
    return value;
}

- (void) setValue:(NSUInteger)_value
{
    value = _value;
}

@end
```

My output:

```
1 1
1 1
2 2
2 2
```

I believe there's a technical document someplace that I read that explains this, but I can't remember where I found it. I believe it said something along the lines of:

`x++` will get changed to `x+=1`

And that `x+=y` will be replaced with `x=x+y`

Further, `x=y.a=z` will be replaced with `y.a=z,x=y.a` (for when you're dealing with properties - not structs)